# electroweak field contribution to the space curvature in GR

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

i've just found out that EM stress energy tensor along with gravitational stress energy contribute to the curvature of space. So, does the electroweak field also contribute to the curvature of space? And what about another field like the higgs field? Sorry if my question is to speculative since i really curious with this kind of stuff

Comment: What gravitational stress energy!?

Comment: well, if i'm mistaken could you please correct me? i'm just wondering what kind of "thing" that contribute to the stress energy tensor in einstein field equation. i think i know (according to wikipedia) that stress energy tensor cause the curvature of space. so let me make it clear, what actually the sources of stress energy tensor beside the electromagnetic field?

Comment: There is no quantum theory of gravity yet, so we cannot say how things like the strong and weak forces or the Higgs interact with gravity, since we simply don't know.